# Estimation of average waiting time

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I'm simulating a procedure that assigns tasks to servers and want to estimate the average waiting time until a task is served (finds a free server).
This procedure runs periodically, thus every task that is rejected in a run can try in the next runs until it finds a free server.
The inter-arrival times of tasks follow an exponential distribution.
Between runs, some tasks may finish.

Is there a way to estimate the average waiting time of tasks?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  You say  you're writing a simulation.  One way is to run the simulation and measure what the average waiting time is in the simulation.  Is that not what you are asking?  Is there a reason you have rejected that approach?  Alternatively, you could try to figure out whether this case can been analyzed using tools from queuing theory, but that might be harder.

Comment: @D.W. I'm interested in deriving this value using a formula. With queuing theory, I should model the process as a queue, there are lots of types of queues. Any hint on what type of queue do I need?

Comment: @Tester Well, are you _simulating_ it or _modelling_ it? Those are two rather different things.

Comment: @ David Richerby Both, but I'm asking about the model. I thought there were some formulas that could give me the average waiting time but it seems that I need queuing theory.

Comment: You need to know the distribution of *service time*.

Comment: @Thumbnail How is this used in order to calculate the waiting time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tasks arrive faster than they can be dealt with, average waiting time is unbounded.

You can probably adapt the [Pollaczek–Khinchine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollaczek%E2%80%93Khinchine_formula) to give an analytic answer to your question:

$$L = \rho + \frac{\rho^2 + \lambda^2 \operatorname{Var}(S)}{2(1-\rho)}$$

where

- $L$ is the mean queue length;
- $\lambda$ is the arrival rate of the Poisson process;
- $1/\mu$ is the mean of the service time distribution $S$;
- $\rho={\lambda \over \mu}$ is the utilization; and
- $Var(S)$ is the variance of the service time distribution $S$.

Comment: It seems that this formula is what I need, thank you.

Comment: @Tester My pleasure. I hadn't understood its power or scope before.